# Is it possible run a spring boot packaged jar with java -cp "jarName.jar" com.hw.Main?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

I am instructed to write a java tool that will run with the following command.

```
java -cp "jarName.jar" com.hw.Main --param=someParam
```

I have created the project with spring boot and can run the executable jar with

```
java -jar "jarName.jar"
```

But when I try the first command console thwors error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.hw.Main
```

Comment: Then your main class is not `com.hw.Main`. Some reason you can't do `java -jar "jarName.jar" --param=someParam`?

Comment: I am starting to get this I guess. I thought all I needed to deliver an executable jar whch can be run with java -cp command. But suddenly it seems like all that they want is a simple java class and the required dependencies packaged within a jarName.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't because Spring Boot executable JARs have its own class loader so your Main class is not visible for the normal class loader.

Either you call it with

```
java -jar jarName.jar --param=someParam
```

or you need to call

```
java -cp jarName.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --param=someParam
```

Becuase org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher is the Spring Boot main class that launches Spring Boot.

But that's the same as java -jar

Comment: Just a followup question, Is there any way that I can leverage the auto configurations of spring boot but package it somehow to run the Main class directly?

Comment: No, but I don't understand why do you wan't to do that?

Comment: No good reason. Just to comply with the instructions for the sample run script given for this specific task. Thanks.